# How to pass parameter with a href and onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass parameter when I click in `<a href>`, first I have this and works fine:

```
    <a href="#" rel="like{{num}}"> I like </a>|

   $("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                ...
            });
```

but I don't know how to pass parameter to that function, so I do this:

```
    <a href="#" rel="like{{num}}"
          onclick="cap(para1, para2)"> I like </a>
```

Finally, in my Javascript I have this simple function:

```
    function cap(para1, para2){
        alert('here');
    }
```

but I obtain this error:

```
ReferenceError: cap is not defined
```

Any idea?

Comment: Would this `cap` function happen to be inside of a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to use [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) :

```
<a href="#" rel="like{{num}}" data-para1="Oh"  data-para2="{{somepara}}"> I like </a>

<script>
function cap(para1, para2){
    alert('here');
}
$("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
   var para1 = this.dataset['para1'];
   var para2 = this.dataset['para2'];
   cap(para1, para2);
});
</script>
```

You may also write it like this if you prefer a more structured approach :

```
<a href="#" rel="like{{num}}" data-params="{'para1':'Oh','para2':'{{somepara}}'}"> I like </a>

$("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
   var params = this.dataset['params'];
   var para1 = params.para1;
   var para2 = params.para2;
```

Note that if the document isn't an HTML5 document you'll have to use the more compatible [data function of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) (but there hardly is any reason not to use HTML5 doctype today) :

```
var para1 = this.data('para1');
```

Comment: The answer is a little misleading, since seems that "data" attribute is related to jQuery, while it has been introduced for HTML5 documents. Hence, this solution will provide a valid markup if he uses HTML5. Of course, it will works also for non HTML5 markups.

Comment: @JeanValjean +1 You're right, you can use the dataset attributes. I'll edit to remove the mention of jQuery. Thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 3):

You may like to try this.

```
<a class="ilike" href="javascript:;" data-p1="abc" data-p2="123"> I like </a>

<script>
    function cap(para1, para2){
        alert('here');
    }

    $(function(){
        $('.ilike').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var p1 = $this.data('p1');
            var p2 = $this.data('p2');
            cap(p1, p2);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via onclick, it's either that 1) you have declared your function in wrong scope or 2) another JS error occurred before the function declaration and caused it to not be executed.

To fix the scope problem, you can try doing `window.cap = function(para1, para2) { ...`

To see if there are any errors, try something like firebug or any browser developer tools and check for errors under console.